# Can't get my $_SESSION right

Tags: php, session, webshop

I hope someone can help me with some troubles I'm having. Currently I'm trying to make a simple webshop. First some information:

I have 2 kinds of products, product a and product b. Both of the products are available in 18 colours and 3 sizes. When you want to buy product a, you simply go to the page of product a, select your colour and your size, and then you add it to your basket.

The problem I'm having is that I can't manage to store the colour and size in the session as wel. Right now I'm storing the id of the product and the quantity in a session like this:

```
 if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
      $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+='1'; 
 }
```

The outcome of the session is: cart_1 1. It means that of the product with the ID 1, 1 has been added to the shopping basket. But what I want to do is that my session also can tell me which colour and size has been submitted. ($_POST['colour'] and $_POST['size']. The problem is that when I store it like this, I will only be able to order 1 of product a and 1 of product b because whenever I want to add another one of product a the 1 from cart_1 will be the same as the one with a different colour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you got all options wrapped in a proper form then you can give each input an id.

Once you're on the current page which handles the form then you can easily access the inputs by referring to their ids.

Example:

```
<form id="mainForm" method="POST" action="scriptUrl.php">
    <input type="text" id="color" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="size" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitFormButton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you can easily access the values as such (once form submitted):

```
$color = isset($_GET['color']) ? $_GET['color'] : "";
$size = isset($_GET['size']) ? $_GET['size'] : "";
```

using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

And you can add this to your sessions if you want, it's preferred to have a single session for a single value, though. That is, if you feel that you really have to use sessions; there are other options, sometimes more suitable.

I know you're not using input texts but you can easily modify your example as such.

It differs between people whether they use GET or POST, I prefer POST.